# Exibir mensagem de erro logo abaixo do form com o action na mesma página!

Tags: php, html

É o seguinte... Estou criando uma espécie de quiz onde o jogador tem que deduzir a resposta e colocá-la no input. Caso correto é redirecionado para o próximo nível, caso esteja errado ele continua na página e uma mensagem e exibida dizendo que não está correto. Pelo menos essa é a ideia kkk.
O problema é que a mensagem que é para aparecer somente quando o jogador erra está aparecendo ao carregar a página, sem mesmo ter colocado a resposta no input, entendem? Como posso dar fix nisso?!!! 
Ah, sim...É minha primeira vez postando uma pergunta, perdoem falta de objetividade ou semelhantes.
[image: aaaaaaaaa]

NoCase | Nível 1

```
    <?php include("includes/fra.php"); ?>
 <div id="wrapper">

 <!-- CAPTURANDO A RESPOSTA -->
 <?php $resposta = isset($_POST["massive"])?$_POST["massive"]:"none";?>

            <div class="text-center">
                <p style="font-size: 22pt;">1¹</p>
                <form action="#wrapper" id="mass" method="POST">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="massive" id="massive" placeholder="RESPOSTA">
                </form>

                 <!-- TÁ PRINTANDO AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA E NÃO QUANDO O USUÁRIO ERRA-->   
                <?php $resposta != 1?print $frases[$rand_keys]: header("Location:example.com");?>


                <button form="mass" type="submit" class="damn_botao"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

            </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando a página carrega `$resposta` não vai ser 1, vai ser `none` pela lógica que tens no inicio do ficheiro, dai ele imprimir sempre a mensagem de erro.

Sugeria que colocasses a verificação e redireccionamento no inicio, até porque o comando `header()` do PHP quando usado para redireccionar, espera que ainda não exista output na página, que no teu caso tens algum HTML, provavelmente vai aparecer uma mensagem de erro, apesar de mesmo assim ser possível fazer o redireccionamento e não se ver. Idealmente evitas isto, até para não estar a ser registado no log de erros.

```
<?php include("includes/fra.php"); ?>
<?php
$errou = false;
// o form foi submetido, então fazemos a verificação se acertou ou não
if (isset($_POST["massive"])) {
    // assumimos que falhou, porque fazemos redirect caso esteja certo e então nunca vamos imprimir a mensagem, mas se não 
    // fosse para fazer redirect, metiamos este $errou = true dentro do else do if para apenas o mudar se falhasse
    $errou = true;
    if ($_POST["massive"] == 1) {
        // acertou!
        header("location:example.php");
    }
}
?>
<div id="wrapper">

// etc..

<!-- TÁ PRINTANDO AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA E NÃO QUANDO O USUÁRIO ERRA-->   
<?php ($errou) ? print $frases[$rand_keys] : ""; ?>
```